# Unable to display specific(cyryllic etc.) characters in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, character, decode, jtextarea

I'm trying to display some text in JTextArea, part of which is in cyryllic.
Instead of proper characters, I receive either boxes or question marks.
The file I'm loading text from looks like this - "polish word - russian word" 
and is encoded in UTF-8.
I've tried several solutions that I include in comments in my code.
EDIT: There are no problems displaying the text in console via System.out.println("");

```
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;
    import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
    import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;

    public class TextDemo extends JFrame implements FocusListener {
        JTextArea jTextArea;
        JScrollPane jCrollPane;
        JButton nextButton;
        ArrayList<String> arrayListPL = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> arrayListRU = new ArrayList<String>();
        //x,y used for getting specific String from the ArrayLists
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            TextDemo mainRunner = new TextDemo();
            mainRunner.RepeatMethod();
        }
        public void RepeatMethod() throws IOException {
            // System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
            // System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
            Repeat();
            TextDemo runner = new TextDemo();
            runner.Repeat();
            runner.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            runner.CreateWindow();
        }

        private void CreateWindow() {

            setSize(400, 600);
            setTitle("Powtórka");
            setResizable(false);
            setVisible(true);
            Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            this.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - this.getSize().width / 2, 
            dim.height / 2 - this.getSize().height / 2);
            jTextArea = new JTextArea();
            jCrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTextArea);
            jCrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 500);
            jTextArea.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
            add(jCrollPane);
            nextButton = new JButton("Next word");
            nextButton.setBounds(0, 500, 400, 100);
            nextButton.setSize(400, 100);
            add(nextButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
            jTextArea.addFocusListener(this);

        }

        public void Repeat() throws IOException {

            File plik = new File("Source//of//the//file.txt");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(plik);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line;


            String[] split;
            String wordRU, wordPL;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // Dividing the pair of words
                split = line.split("-");
                wordRU = split[0].trim();
                wordPL = split[1].trim();
                wordRU = new String(wordRU.getBytes("Cp1250"), "UTF-8");
                wordPL = new String(wordPL.getBytes("Cp1250"), "UTF-8");
                arrayListPL.add((wordPL));
                arrayListRU.add((wordRU));

            }

            br.close();

        }

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {

            jTextArea.setText(jTextArea.getText() + "\n" + 
            arrayListPL.get(x));
            if (x < arrayListPL.size()) {
                x++;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
            jTextArea.setText(jTextArea.getText() + "\n" + 
            arrayListRU.get(y));
            if (y < arrayListRU.size()) {
                y++;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I created the file "file.txt" with content, ran your code, but can see only empty window. Please create minimal working program, with strings as constants and not taken from file.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov It's a working version, only the controls are very primitive. In order to display anything you need to focus either on button or text field.

Comment: `new String(wordRU.getBytes("Cp1250"), "UTF-8")` is some kind of cargo-cult reencoding: it looks like it might do smoething meaningful while in reality when it does anything it is almost never what is expected...

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the file with a `FileReader`, and this convenience class assumes that the text file is in the "platform default encoding", whatever that is on your machine.

You'd better use `InputStreamReader` where you can explicitly specify the file encoding as "UTF-8", to match your file.

Your code lines

```
            wordRU = new String(wordRU.getBytes("Cp1250"), "UTF-8");
            wordPL = new String(wordPL.getBytes("Cp1250"), "UTF-8");
```

should not be necessary, then.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the lines

```
        wordRU = new String(wordRU.getBytes("Cp1250"), "UTF-8");
        wordPL = new String(wordPL.getBytes("Cp1250"), "UTF-8");
```

and clicked the text field, and it showed all the words from file.txt correctly, both cyrillic and polish letters. No other changes was made.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it :) the issue was with the loaded file. I changed the way of writing to the file in another class:

```
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("source\\of\\file"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(osw);
```